# Python 3.1 installed from Macports on 10.5.8 - shelve error (bug or not?)

Tags: python, macos, macports, shelve

I am running python 3.1.4 from macports and I am attempting to use the shelve module here. I can use it successfully on another dev. machine (different OS, etc.) so I am not sure what I may be doing incorrectly...

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the error
"dbm.error: db type could not be determined"
 (I searched for the error message but found no info - I even tried to force the protocl=2 to see if that might help but it did not)

Here's the interactive session:

```
Python 3.1.4 (default, Oct  7 2011, 15:58:53) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
>>> import shelve
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> locker = shelve.open('myshelf',protocol=2)
>>> locker['a'] = a
>>> locker.close()
>>> exit()


Python 3.1.4 (default, Oct  7 2011, 15:58:53) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
>>> import shelve
>>> locker = shelve.open('myshelf',protocol=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/shelve.py", line 231, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/shelve.py", line 215, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/dbm/__init__.py", line 84, in open
    raise error[0]("db type could not be determined")
dbm.error: db type could not be determined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the MacPorts port or in Python 3.  For me, your sample works with a current MacPorts Python 2.7.2 but fails with a current MacPorts Python 3.2.2 in the same way as you've reported.  MacPorts automatically builds and includes `gdbm` as a database manager for Python 3 ports; for Python 2 it includes both Berkeley `DB4.6` and `gdbm`.  It looks like the MacPorts 2.7.2 is using db46 and works but 3.2.2 fails using `gdbm`; presumably the MacPorts 3.1 port is similar.  This should be investigated further.

Update: If you are using an up-to-date MacPorts installation, this is likely the problem reported in http://bugs.python.org/issue13007  It looks like there was a fix to support the latest `gdbm 1.9` and beyond - the current MacPorts version is 1.9.1. That fix was applied after Python 3.2.2 was released (it will be in 3.2.3); the MacPorts folks should backport that to their Python ports.

Comment: Hmmm, I had hope that this was NOT the answer. Hard to believe that I am the first person to try and use shelve with python 3.1 after installing from Macports but there you go...</br>

Comment: Any thoughts on a temporary work around? I don't want to start monkey-patching it but if I can pass a parameter into my shelve call to force the use of a different db that would (at least) get me past this roadblock...

Comment: Sorry!  Also note that 3.1 has been obsoleted by 3.2. It would be a good idea to move to it; there are a lot of fixes and imporvements in 3.2 and 3.1 is now in security-fix-only mode.

Comment: It should be easy enough to manually apply the 3.2 patch to 3.1 until it is fixed in MacPorts:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/7a41855b6196

Comment: The file is at /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/dbm/__init__.py

Comment: Great! I did it and it worked perfectly - thanks for the (incredibly specific) help! I SHOULD update to 3.2 but I am working on a 3.1 project for the moment and have to muddle through...

Comment: Glad to be of help. By the way, if you ask a question here on SO, the expectation is that you'll either mark an answer as accepted or refine your question until you do get an answer that you can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use MacPorts or Homebrew to install *ndbm*.   Shelve with use that to create the database.  When opening the file later, *shelve* will call *dbm.whichdb* and will successfully recognize the file.

Comment: Hmmm, seems that ndbm is the culprit but macports wraps that up into the python 3.1 install. I'll have to get it elsewhere and see what I can break tring to install it :-)